# How to multi-thread two counters in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am studying thread at the moment and am writing code to alternatively count numbers.
One thread should count from 0 to 100 if boolean reverse is false, and one thread should count from 100 to 0 if reverse is true.

What I have done so far is:

```
public class Count implements Runnable {

private int start = 0;
private int finish = 0;
private boolean reverse = false;
private Printer printer;
private String prefix;

public Counter(String prefix, int start, int finish, boolean reverse, Printer printer) throws Exception {
    if (finish < start && printer == null) {
        throw new Exception("finish must be equal or greater than start, no nulls allowed.");
    } else {
        this.start = start;
        this.finish = finish;
        this.reverse = reverse;
        this.printer = printer;
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {

    if (reverse) {


        for (int i = start; i <= finish; i++) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                printer.setPrefix(prefix);
                printer.setCount(i);
                printer.print();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Already interrupted.");
            }
        }
    } else {

        for (int i = finish; i >= start; i--) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                printer.setPrefix(prefix);
                printer.setCount(i);
                printer.print();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Already interrupted.");
            }
        }
    }
}
}




public class Printer {

    String prefix = null;
    int count = 0;

    public Printer() {

    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(prefix + ": " + count);

    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Printer printer = new Printer();
        Thread counter = new Thread(new Counter("Prefix1", 0, 100, false, printer));
        Thread counter2 = new Thread(new Counter("Prefix2", 0, 100, true, printer));
        counter.start();
        counter2.start();


    }
}
```

When I run the program, the output goes like this:

```
Prefix2: 0
Prefix2: 0
Prefix1: 99
Prefix2: 1
Prefix2: 98
Prefix2: 98
Prefix1: 97
Prefix2: 3
Prefix1: 4
Prefix1: 4
```

Can anyone please fix or tell me how to correct the code to print out them alternatively in correct manners?

Expected Output:

```
Prefix1: 1
Prefix2: 100
Prefix1: 2
Prefix2: 99
Prefix1: 3
Prefix2: 98
and so on...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's not clear how this class is used to generate that output.

Comment: One thing you could benefit form is learning about the *happens-before* relationship. It might explain a lot about whats wrong here.

Comment: You've shown the actual output you are getting when you run your code. Now [edit] your question and post how you want the output to appear. It's not clear to me what you mean by _print out them alternatively in correct manners_

Comment: @Abra okay, i will edit the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with your code for some time, my final version, below, is not exactly what you requested, but it is very close, in my opinion.

Java 5 introduced many [concurrency utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/index.html), including [lock objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html). (Refer to *Concurrency* lesson in *Essential Classes* trail which is part of Oracle's java tutorials.) Another reference that helped me understand java's concurrency utilities was the book *Thinking in Java* (4th edition) by Bruce Eckel.

Therefore, I used class [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) rather than synchronization. I also made all the methods in your `Printer` class synchronized, since they are called from multiple threads. Here is my version of that class. I added the thread ID to the `print()` method so that you can correlate the printed output with the calling thread.

```java
public class Printer {
    String prefix;
    int count;

    public synchronized void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public synchronized void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public synchronized void print() {
        System.out.printf("[%d] %s: %3d%n", Thread.currentThread().getId(), prefix, count);
    }
}
```

Here is my version of your `Counter` class.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Counter implements Runnable {
    private static ReentrantLock theLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private int start = 0;
    private int finish = 0;
    private boolean reverse = false;
    private Printer printer;
    private String prefix;

    public Counter(String prefix, int start, int finish, boolean reverse, Printer printer)
            throws Exception {
        if (finish < start && printer == null) {
            throw new Exception("finish must be equal or greater than start, no nulls allowed.");
        }
        else {
            this.start = start;
            this.finish = finish;
            this.reverse = reverse;
            this.printer = printer;
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (reverse) {
            for (int i = start; i <= finish; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    theLock.lock();
                    printer.setPrefix(prefix);
                    printer.setCount(i);
                    printer.print();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Already interrupted.");
                }
                finally {
                    if (theLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                        theLock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int i = finish; i >= start; i--) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    theLock.lock();
                    printer.setPrefix(prefix);
                    printer.setCount(i);
                    printer.print();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Already interrupted.");
                }
                finally {
                    if (theLock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                        theLock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Printer printer = new Printer();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        es.execute(new Counter("Prefix1", 0, 100, false, printer));
        es.execute(new Counter("Prefix2", 0, 100, true, printer));
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, you can't completely control the scheduling of threads in java, hence if you run the above code you may see in the output lines like the following

```
[14] Prefix2:   0
[13] Prefix1: 100
[13] Prefix1:  99
[14] Prefix2:   1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is that you need something that manages who's turn it is. Threads will not go synchronously (ofcourse duh). What can happen is this:

```
Thread 1 Runs
Thread 1 Runs
Thread 1 Runs
Thread 2 Runs
```

Even if you set prio's the same. I've made you and example to show how you can set it up:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        threadPoolExecutor.execute(() -> {
            int i = 10;
            while (i > 0) {
                if (atomicBoolean.get()) {
                    System.out.println("plus: " + i);
                    i--;
                    atomicBoolean.set(false);
                }
            }
        });
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(() -> {
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= 10) {
                if (!atomicBoolean.get()) {
                    System.out.println("minus: " + i);
                    ++i;
                    atomicBoolean.set(true);
                }
            }
        });
        threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

"Atomic" variable guarantees that it will be thread safe. You can't use a normal boolean to do your "who's turn is it" management.

Comment: This is a fine example, however it might be worth talking about **volatile** because that is what **Atomic** implementations are.

Comment: You are correct, @Jason. This is just an answer to the problem but it's best if he researches more deeply on fundamentals of threading.

Comment: Yeah that is perfectly fair, great job on the answer eh! +1

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should consider is that maybe Counter should have a **single responsibility** such as counting. Printer should have the single responsibility of printing that counter to the console. You should only create a single Counter object and share it between the two threads. At the moment you have 2 threads with 2 Counter objects. The issue with this is that thread 1 and thread 2 don't know whether they should increment or decrement.

The solution to your problem would be to create a **[happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)** relationship with each thread on the single Counter object. ThreadA might be in charge of incrementing, and ThreadB might be in charge of decrementing. Counter would be the **shared resource** that should be **[synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)**.

If you look at the resources i've provided, rather Oracle has provided, you should be able to easily complete your task. If you want me to provide an example I can, but you'll have to implement some of the features i've listed in your main post to show you've made an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are `synchronizing` on different `locks` so you're not synchronizing at all.  The `synchronized run()` statement uses the `intrinsic` monitor from each instance of `count`.  So try the following:

- Remove the synchronous statement from run
- Establish a common `lock` on which to synchronize.  Put the following in your `count` class.

```
public final static Object lock = new Object();
```

- Then do this to each of your `try blocks`

```
synchronized (lock) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        printer.setPrefix(prefix);
        printer.setCount(i);
        printer.print();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Already interrupted.");
    }
}
```

- Now reduce your count from 100 to 10 so you can track events easier.
- It's important to synchronize inside of your loops.  Otherwise, the loops will finish when they each grab the lock and it won't be very exciting.

Here are my changes.

```
    public final static Object lock = new Object();

    @Override
    public  void run() {
        if (reverse) {

            for (int i = start; i <= finish; i++) {

             synchronized(lock) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        printer.setPrefix(prefix);
                        printer.setCount(i);
                        printer.print();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Already interrupted.");
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            for (int i = finish; i >= start; i--) {
                synchronized(lock) {
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        printer.setPrefix(prefix);
                        printer.setCount(i);
                        printer.print();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Already interrupted.");
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

And here is my most recent run

```
Prefix1: 10
Prefix1: 9
Prefix2: 0
Prefix1: 8
Prefix2: 1
Prefix2: 2
Prefix2: 3
Prefix2: 4
Prefix2: 5
Prefix2: 6
Prefix2: 7
Prefix2: 8
Prefix2: 9
Prefix2: 10
Prefix1: 7
Prefix1: 6
Prefix1: 5
Prefix1: 4
Prefix1: 3
Prefix1: 2
Prefix1: 1
Prefix1: 0
```

Comment: this outputs like this:
thread1: 1
thread1: 2
thread1: 3
thread2: 3
thread2: 2
thread2: 1

Comment: Run it again. If you synchronized both loops as above and established a common lock the outputs should be asynchronous and not in any predictable order.  Did you remove the synchronous statement from run()? It won't matter but it's not required.

Comment: I did as you instructed but it prints out all the thread1 first and then prints all the thread2...

Comment: That makes no sense to me.  I'm going to temporarily post my code.

Comment: You can increase the range to 50 and/or increase the delay to say 300ms in each loop.  But threads are unpredictable.

Comment: Your posted code shows a `Counter` constructor and your threads are using `new Counter` and not `new Count`.  Is that an issue?  Your class is named `Count`